# PHP Арифметическая операция вычитание

Tags: php

```
var_dump(floatval($this->amount)); \\float(18000)
var_dump($sum); \\float(18000)
var_dump(floatval($this->amount)-$sum); die; \\float(-3.6379788070917E-12)
```

Что не так с вычитанием?

Answer (score 1):

[`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.floatval.php) нельзя использовать с объектами в этом случае возникнет ошибка уровня **E_NOTICE** и функция вернет **1**.

Может быть проблема в этом.

Comment: $this->amount - это стринг вообщето '18000.00', но даже без floatval() возвращает то же, пока решил проблему через round($result,2) результата

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк amount хранить как строку........ммм, что-то новенькое............лучше храните его сразу в нормальном виде